# How to create a text file in a folder

Tags: macos, finder, file

In windows I right click and then there is an option to create a text file.

How to do so in mac?

Comment: It's unreal to me that this is such a difficult task. The below answers work, but good luck explaining them to a non-technical friend or family member.

Comment: In mac it's not obvious how

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sE_V0vzNTWQ

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you have the Finder window open, use Spotlight to open TextEdit. When you're ready to save the file, option+drag the text file icon from the title bar of TextEdit into the Finder window where you want to save it.

Comment: 1. The title bar of TextEdit does not have a text file icon. 2. TextEdit does not offer to save it as a simple txt file. Only RTF, .html, odt, word and webarchive is possible

Comment: 1. The title bar icon appears shortly after creating the new document. 2. Textedit can be configured to use plain text by default. This means new files will be saved as txt not rtf. 3. I had to option+drag to get it to move the file to the desired location, rather than create a shortcut.

Comment: This works as long as you set a file name first by clicking the downwards pointing caret at the right hand side of "Untitled". Just set the name, leave "where" as it is, and you are able to drag.

Comment: As of High Sierra, the easiest way to save as text is to select "Format" > "Make Plain Text" before saving a new file.

Comment: You don't have give it any filename. Just Opt+drag the icon on the title bar. Tested on MacOS Montery v12.0.1

Comment: This worked for me but it made a copy in the new location and only save further edits to the original location

Comment: Worsssst answer ever, in the entire stackexchage constelation

Comment: yeah, I remember I once got here... this sucks alot still in the end of 2022

Comment: Doest not work reliably - icon is missing sometimes.

Comment: On Ventura I need to option-click the TextEdit title bar icon, _hold_ for a fraction of a second, then drag the icon to Finder. If I option click and drag immediately, it doesn't "pick" up the icon, but moves the window instead. Apparently the file is copied though, not moved, so in my case I get a duplicate in iCloud or wherever the default location is.

Comment: @Marecky Surprisingly, it was accepted by the OP. I thought the point of asking the question was to know the equivalent of Win's right-click txt creation. Which proves that the _SE constellation_ is partly composed of the people who ask questions.

Answer (score 102):

You can also do this in Terminal. Go to the directory where you want to create the file, then run the following:

```
touch file.txt
```

Or redirect 'nothing' to a text file

```
> file.txt
```

Comment: any easy way to go the directory that I want? Unlike in windows I can't even copy that directory as text

Comment: In Terminal, you can type cd, then a space, then drag a folder onto the Terminal window and press Return to go to that folder.

Comment: In 10.8 and later you can also drag the folder on a Terminal window while holding command. Or if you copy the folder, ⌘V inserts its path in Terminal.

Comment: None are convenience for users. For a text file, I have to open up a terminal type a command and drag and drop then type another command! Come on!

Comment: You can always use the full path on the command line, and generally don't *need* to `cd` (though it can be convenient). `touch "$HOME"/Documents/fnord.txt` will create `fnord.txt` in your `Documents` folder regardless of your current directory. `touch /etc/moo` will create a file in the system directory `/etc` (provided you have the privileges to create a file there, which you actually probably don't have). `touch path/to/foo` will create `foo` in the directory `path/to` which is the subdirectory `to` of the subdirectory `path` of the current directory.

Comment: (The directories need to exist; you can `mkdir -p path/to` before doing the `touch`, or figure out how to use the command `install` to do both in one go.)

Comment: @malhobayyeb My interpretation of this answer is "if you are okay with working on the command line anyway, it's not hard", rather than "you have to use the command line for this".

Comment: At least since macos 10.11, you can: **select the folder** in the Finder, then menu `Finder > Services > New Terminal in folder` and typing `> file.txt` will do the job. Since the Terminal is opened in the current folder, you don't need to copy/paste or type its name. In case, this service is not present in your Services menu, you can add it with the `Services Preferences`. Don't forget to select the folder first. HTH

Comment: That's why I use Mac and Ubuntu only for development in some cases and Windows for anything else and also for development

Comment: A more convenient way to do this nowadays would be to use [DTerm](https://github.com/muhqu/dterm), a free app that lets you open a mini command prompt in any Finder window.

Comment: So complicated, tired of reading how to create file in folder. What's wrong with this world?  User oriented operating system, damn...

Comment: cannot explain this to my mom

Comment: @user4951 Copying a file or folder **path** is actually very easy on a Mac: just select a file or a older and press `⌥` + `⌘` + `c`. Read this answer: [How to copy path of a file in Mac OS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/338899/316652).

Answer (score 85):

The simplest version **does not require a file or folder to be selected**, and **adds a keyboard shortcut** of your choice.

**Part 1: Create a new Quick Action (was Service)**

In Automator, create a new **Quick Action** (previously called a Service):

[image]

From the left side, click Utilities then drag "Run Applescript" over to the right panel.

Change the two pulldown menus at the top of the right panel to read:

> Workflow receives <kbd>no input</kbd> in <kbd>Finder.app</kbd>

Replace ALL the purple script with:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set txt to make new file at (the target of the front window) as alias with properties {name:"empty.txt"}
    select txt
end tell
```

Save the Service as "New Empty Text File" (.workflow extension will be added automatically).

This service is now available under the **Finder** menu in the Finder.

**Part 2: Create a Keyboard Shortcut**

Under **System Preferences › Keyboard › Shortcuts › Services**, scroll down to **General** (it's at the end).

You will see **New Empty Text File** listed with "none" as the shortcut.

Click on none and **type the shortcut** of your choice (I used **cmd alt N**):

[image]

You can now type your shortcut in the Finder whenever you want to create a new, empty, text document.

Thanks to Syreeni, whose answer made this possible, and to RoG (comment below) who contributed the line that automatically selects the new file.

Comment: If "untitled.txt" already exists then the service throws an error message you have to then deal with. Suggest you code in some error handling.

Comment: You can simply delete " with properties {name:"untitled.txt"}" and it will create sequential empty files. I left it in because I wanted my answer to be as brief as possible and personally, if there's already an empty file, I'd rather be alerted and use it than create a second one.

Comment: I added a second applescript line `tell application "Finder" to select the file "untitled.txt"` so that I can easily find the new file, and hit the return key to rename it.

Comment: Greate idea, I added it to answer and credited you at the bottom.

Comment: Great idea, but I would like to use it to create a file on the Desktop. It works everywhere except the Desktop, where it says there is an error (without specifying what error), do you have any idea about why this happens?

Comment: @Kubuntuer82 [This answer to “Right-click, create a new text file. How?”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/94847/21473) has additional code to check if the desktop is focused and to create the file differently if so.

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: Unbelievable (and unacceptable) that we have to waste time making a custom action in order to do a simple and basic thing that a GUI should have as a default. The solution works, perfectly, and this should be the accepted answer, even if it would be a standard feature of the OS.

Comment: I used this applescript in the script editor. Saved it as an app.  added this icon to the app in finder http://jugglegood.com/out/finder-control-button.png . Then, added the app to my finder control bar so it's always ready to go. the button is a little smaller than the add folder button, but it doesn't look too bad...  finder asks permission the first time, but then it will work quickly.

Comment: What terminal does easily with one simple command so should gui. Thanks for making this possible!

Comment: However note the defect that pressing the keyboard shortcut again while the filename is still empty.txt will render an error instead of the nicer solution of creating an extra empty file

Comment: First, I had trouble finding where the "service" was located. Click on Finder, and at the top of the screen, in the menu bar, click on Finder>Services then scan down to the bottom of the sub menu , and you will see New Empty Text File. Second, you can't just click on a folder and have the text file created in that folder.  Instead, you have to double click on the folder, so that Finder actually enters the folder.  Third, I liked the solution that `lodeOfCode` linked to better.  I can just click on an icon in the Finder window to add the text file.  I'm using `macOS 12.3.1`.

Comment: How to make it open the text file just created? That would be more efficient. I tried this, but I get a permissions error:
tell application "Finder"
    set txt to make new file at (the target of the front window) as alias with properties {name:"empty.txt"}
    open txt
end tell

Comment: "cmd alt N" shortcut doesn't work for me as it seems to be overridden by an action that opens a new window. As al alternative I used "cmd shift M".

Answer (score 25):

Here is my workaround:

1. Do this once, create an empty text file in your desktop to serve as template.
2. <kbd>Opt</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>-drag this file to the folder to make a copy.

Comment: This solution is great -- my small tweak: put the blank template in your Downloads folder to keep the Desktop cleaner. Then click the Downloads folder in your Dock and option-drag as you said.

Answer (score 18):

There's two ways to do this, the easiest is the first option;

1. Open *TextEdit* and type whatever you need into it then save it to the location you want the file to live.

   You can open *TextEdit* quickly by invoking *Spotlight* and being typing *Tex...*, you should see the *top hit* is the app you want so you can just press enter to open it.
2. This is more involved and will require you to create an AppleScript.  The contents of the script needs to be:

   `tell application "Finder" to make new file at (the target of the front window) as alias`

Export the script as an *Application* somewhere safe and make sure you tick *Run Only* when saving it.  Then drag the resulting file to the *toolbar* in *Finder*

This will then allow you to create a blank text file in what ever window you're viewing in *Finder* called `untitled` which you can then double click to edit in *TextEdit*

[The Ultimate Beginner’s Guide To AppleScript](http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/automation/the-ultimate-beginners-guide-to-applescript-2/), is good if you want to know more about AppleScript.

Comment: @apricot Mavericks and above requires that you hold Command+Option while dragging in order to be able to drag it to the Finder toolbar. Be sure to export the script as an Application first as mentioned above (File > Export).

Comment: Hm, for me the script creates new `untitled` files in Applications folder and not in the current folder I'm in.

Comment: For the AppleScript method, I need to right click a folder for the Service show. How can I show it by just right clicking empty space in Finder?

Comment: Dragging it to the toolbar does nothing for me. Can you post a gif or something?

Comment: I couldn't type whatever I wanted, because TextEdit opened the recent file. When I found the command "New file" (in the dock's context menu!), it created an rtf file!

Answer (score 11):

> Check my answer at - [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/14118/easiest-way-to-create-a-new-text-file-in-a-finder-window-on-osx/825408#825408).
>
> **NOTE:** After the introduction of SIP, this app does *not* work unless you disable it. [Read more](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/sip.html) on how to do it, but it is ill-advised.

Try [**XtraFinder**](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/).

This app is just great, solved all my basic needs after switching from a windows platform like adding "New File" in context menu and finder toolbar, etc. Some of the features as listed on their website are -

> XtraFinder add Tabs and features to Mac Finder.
>
> • Tabs & Dual Panel.
>
> • Arrange folders on top.
>
> • Cut & Paste.
>
> • Global hotkeys.
>
> • "Copy Path", "Show Hidden Items", "Hide Desktop", "Refresh", "New File", "Copy to", "Move to", "New Terminal Here", "Make Symbolic Link", "Contents", "Attributes", … .
>
> • Legacy label for OSX 10.9 & 10.10. Light text on dark background. Transparent window.
>
> • Colorful icons in Sidebar.
>
> • Size of selected items in Status Bar.
>
> • Automatically adjust width of columns.
>
> • Press Enter or Return to open selection.
>
> • Display folder item count in List view.
>
> • Middle-click to open folder in new window or new tab.
>
> • Much more.

I use this app with OS X 10.9.5 and did not encounter any issues with it. It has native os x icon style which looks good on retina screens also. Here is a screenshot of my finder toolbar -

[image: Finder Toolbar]

*Ps. this app is also free!*

Comment: This no longer works on OSX.11 without disabling integrity protection which even the software author discourages.

Answer (score 9):

[New File Applescript with Toolbar Icon](https://github.com/RomanSmolka/finder-new-file)

Found this open source gem. Can either use the .App or add the Applescript manually. Will add a New File widget to the Finder toolbar.

[image: New File Toolbar Icon]

Comment: thanks, apple are so annoying to not have this natively.

Comment: That's the most elegant solution I found of all.  I built my own application from the `.applescript` that's locally signed and is trusted by my Mac.

Comment: Bravo!!! Thank you

Comment: This is an elegant solution, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

How to create as an Automator Service (OS X El Capitan 10.11.5):

- Open *Automator* and select *File > New > Service*.
- Next, choose *Folders* from the drop-down menu *Service receives selected ...*
- In the *Actions* menu search for and add *Run AppleSript* or drag & drop it from the *Utilities* category.
- Copy and paste this script into the *Run AppleScript action*:

  ```
  tell application "Finder" to make new file at (the target of the front window) as alias with properties {name:"untitled.txt"}
  ```
- Save the service as *New Text File* or similar.

You should now be able to right-click on a folder and find *Services > New Text File*.

**Note:** You'll get an error if you try to add a second *untitled.txt* to the same folder.

Comment: If you don't specify name of the file, the service would number the files like so `untitled`, then `untitled 2` and so on wuthout causing an error.

Comment: This works pretty well thanks. Is there a way to add two features? Can the new file be saved directly as 'newfile.txt'?  At the moment I get the Services option only when I right click on a Folder Icon, is there a way to get that option while clicking on a Finder window?

Comment: Any way to make it so that it doesn't require right clicking a folder? I was hoping I could do this by just right clicking on empty space in a Finder window.

Comment: @EhteshamHasan Unfortunately the Finder doesn't display the services menu (or anything this can hook into ) when not selecting any input files or folders.

Comment: EhteshamHasan and Andrea Di Biagio, see my answer below. You don't have to select a file folder for it to work, and the service is available under the Finder menu even when nothing is selected.

Comment: In 10.14 (Mojave) the Automator has no File->New->Service. File->New leads to a dialog who's only options are Workflow, Application, Quick Action, Print Plugin, Folder Action, Calendar Alarm, Image Capture Plugin, Dictation Command

Answer (score 5):

Here's my script for creating new files from a store of templates.

I run it with FastScripts using a keyboard shortcut, but you can save it to an applet and put it in the menu bar, create an automator action, etc.

-ccs

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--       Author: Christopher Stone 
--      Created: 2012-10-26 : 01:27
--     Modified: 2012-10-26 : 18:26
--  Application: Finder
--      Purpose: Create a new file from a file-type list in the front Finder window using
--             : template files stored in a folder.
-- Dependencies: Template files provided by the user.
--    Templates: Auto-creates a Text template - others are for the user to supply.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

try

  try
    set templateFolderPath to ((path to application support from user domain as text) & "Script_Support:New_File_Here!:")
    set templateFolder to alias templateFolderPath
  on error
    set newFilesHereFolder to quoted form of (POSIX path of templateFolderPath)
    set textTemplate to newFilesHereFolder & "Text_Template.txt"
    do shell script "mkdir -p " & newFilesHereFolder & ";
     touch " & textTemplate & ";
     open -R " & textTemplate
    return
  end try

  tell application "Finder"
    if front window exists then
      set winTarget to target of front window as alias
      set fileTemplateList to name of files of templateFolder

      tell me to set fileType to choose from list fileTemplateList with title "New_File_Here! Templates" with prompt ¬
        "Pick One or More:" default items {get item 1 of fileTemplateList} with multiple selections allowed

      if fileType ≠ false then
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to (return & templateFolderPath)
        set itemsToCopy to paragraphs of ((templateFolder as text) & fileType)

        repeat with i in itemsToCopy
          set i's contents to i as alias
        end repeat

        set copiedFiles to duplicate itemsToCopy to winTarget
        select copiedFiles
      end if

    else
      error "No windows open in Finder!"
    end if
  end tell

on error e number n
  set e to e & return & return & "Num: " & n
  tell me to set dDlg to display dialog e with title "ERROR!" buttons {"Cancel", "Copy", "OK"} default button "OK"
  if button returned of dDlg = "Copy" then set the clipboard to e
end try

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This solution is great if you're got Alfred with the powerpack so you can just use a hotkey over a finder window

Answer (score 5):

On el capitan (and probably others) the best solution I found is to download the script here:

http://www.codium.co.nz/touch%5Fhere%5Fapp/

Then open a finder window, right click on the top bar > customize toolbar
and put the script on your toolbar.

Now you have it in one click for all your finder windows, and it will prompt you what file name you want instead of just creating a dumb file name.

UPDATE: I just made a repo for that, which exposes the source code: 
https://github.com/lingtalfi/newFileWithPrompt

Comment: When I enter the name of a file and click OK, I get `You don't have permission to create a file here`

Comment: @JustAMartin Any method of creating a file will fail if you don't have the required permissions.

Comment: But I can save a file in the same folder when using a text editor. It's just that script that failed with the error, but other programs allow to save there.

Comment: Thanks for this! By far the best solution I ran into after much googling. Such a basic function that MacOS doesn't support.

Answer (score 5):

There's a very simple method using *touch* command in Automator:

Create a new service in Automator

[image: Create a Service in Automator]

Set it to receive selected "files or folders" in Finder

[image]

Add a Run Shell Script with Pass input "as arguments" and paste this code into the shell:

```
for d in "$@"; do
cd "$d"
touch untitled.txt
done
```

[image: paste code]

Save it.

### Done!

---

And if you want to add a keyboard shortcut to it, go to System Preferences > Keyboard

[image: add shortcut]

Enjoy ^^

#### Alternative code to handle files

The above code requires a folder to be selected to work, and does nothing if a file is selected. Changing the shell script code to the code snippet below will handle files as well, and create an empty file next to the selected file:

```bsh
for df in "$@"; do

   if [[ -d "$df" ]]; then
      d="$df"

   elif [[ -e "$df" ]]; then
      d="$(dirname "$df")"

   fi

   touch "$d"/empty.txt
done
```

Comment: this looks great -- didn't know you could run shell scripts like this; I've never wanted to take the time to learn Applescript, it's so esoteric

Comment: adding a small edit suggestion to handle files a well -- in my test, the original code did nothing when the service was run while a _file_ was selected, rather than a folder

Comment: But for this you need a shortcut. Is it also possible with a right click? So far I haven't found a solution ...

Answer (score 4):

Reading through the previous answers, I decided to make a little [AppleScript applet](https://github.com/RomanSmolka/finder-new-file) you can add to the toolbar in Finder. When clicked, it creates a new blank file in the current directory, letting you rename it immediately – just like in Windows.

In the future, I plan to implement it also as a Finder extension.

Answer (score 2):

I use [PathFinder](http://cocoatech.com/pathfinder/) as a replacement for Finder and it includes this in its right-click context menu. It is prboably too expensive a solution just for this but if you want to have a better Finder for other reasons as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are two useful utilities that you can download and install that will enable you to create a new text file (or RTF file) in a currently-open folder that you are viewing using the Finder.

The utilities are called NewTextFileHere and NewRTFHere and can be downloaded from

http://mac.softpedia.com/developer/Jonas-Wisser-37498.html

Icons for either of these apps can then be included on all of your Finder windows.

Comment: Or use "stationary Pad" in the finder, which does this, and is a built in OS function.

Answer (score 2):

I just downloaded [New File](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/new-file-menu/id1064959555?) menu (2$) from the app store and it seems to work fine.

Comment: This is the best answer of all. $2 later and I can create different kinds of files easily, with the option to name them and/or open them straightaway if desired. Accessible by keyboard shortcut, context menu, or toolbar, whichever is preferred. This should just be how a Mac works by default!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Easy New File Creator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easy-new-file-free/id1163105418?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo%3D4), a free app for macOS.

Using **Easy New File Creator**, a finder extension you can add create new file functionality in the Finder context menu. You can customise the file name and extension for file to be created.

Answer (score 2):

On the mac in finder, select a .txt file, hold option and drag it to make a copy, then edit it as usual.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the many things that [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai) does for me. It has a pre-defined action "Create New File in Current Folder" for this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Amazing demonstration @Andrew Swift. I would add a few things to the script. First, add "at insertion location as alias" to cover the desktop. Second, ((current date) as string) as part of the file name to ensure that you can create multiple empty text files with different names (Timestamps are cool)

```
on tell application "Finder"
    set txt to make new file at insertion location as alias with properties {name:"New_text_" & ((current date) as string) & ".txt"}
    select txt
end tell
```

Comment: Hi Kano, welcome to Ask Different! It’s good that you’re contributing to our community. However, could you place this as a **comment** to Andrew Swift’s answer instead of making a new answer altogether?

Comment: Hey Brick, I have actually tried to reply to his comment but I was not able to do it, since my reputation point was too low to do so. If you know a way to make it happen please let me know. Meanwhile I just wanted to leave the message here anyways since people were looking for a way to do this.

Comment: I believe you can ask good questions or give good answers which will quickly increase your reputation points so that you can comment. You can see this link for more information: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: That is what I intended to do. The code I posted is an answer to the specific question. It just happens that my solution was based on Andrew Swifts :) Regardless, I will be more mindful of where I post things, thank you.

Comment: Ah okay, must be my bad then.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.macworld.com/article/1151236/createnewfileservice.html) from MacWorld indicates how to create a service that creates a new text file.

Comment: Please provide a summary of the method. Links become outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Open Finder and navigate to Applications. Locate TextEdit.app and open it. Select Format--->Make Plain Text (this can also be done using Shift+Command+T). Select File--->Save... and you can save this as a real empty plain text file of 0 bytes.

(I am using macOS Catalina now and saw that there were no clear, simple answers to this question, so I decided to post this as an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Mac being mac, this is the simplest I could think of, out of the box:

1. Right click on folder, select `Services > New Terminal at Folder`
2. On terminal type `touch yourfile.txt`
3. `Cmd+Q` on terminal

Comment: How is this different than the answers already provided?  The second-highest voted answer is almost identical to your answer.

Comment: Almost. Starting a terminal, cd'ing to a directory, and touching a file is more verbose than right click'ing and simply touching a file.

Comment: Instead of creating a new answer for substantially the same info, you should [gain more reputation on the site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) so you can add comments and edit existing answers.  That's the preferred method on the SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

I use [this](https://www.packal.org/workflow/create-new-file-finder-file-type-templates) plugin in [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/)

> Simply load the folder you would like the new file to appear in, in the Finder. Then call up Alfred, and type “new “. You can now enter a new filename to be used for your new file. E.g. “index.html”. Your new file will be created in the folder for you instantly.

[image: screenshot of the Alfred plugin]

Answer (score 0):

My method to make an empty text file is crude but simpler:

Simply create a new text file in TextEdit, then save as Rich Text Format "whatever.rtf"

Then press cmd-shift-T to convert it to plain text.

Say yes when the dialog box pops up asking to confirm change.

And you're done.

P.S. Once you have changed it to a .txt file. You can then edit it with any text editor and save it and it will remain a .txt file.

Comment: This doesn't actually work. Renaming the file doesn't turn it into a different format, and TextEdit will still open it as RTF, regardless of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, applications create files, not the Finder.
So to create a file (or a text one), you need to use an App creating one; for example TextEdit, BBEdit, TextWrangler, etc.

To save the file, you call 'File > Save'. This is standard on macOS and all apps have it.

'File > Save' offers a dialogue for you to enter a name to your file and to choose the folder in which to save it to.

To save in a specific folder without the need of navigating to it previously:

- open the folder in which you want to save your (text) file in the
  Finder
- while editing your file… call 'File > Save' and drag the folder
  icon from the open window in Finder to the 'Where' popup of the Save
  dialogue: [image]
  This changes the location where the file will be saved.
- click on 'Save'.

If the file was already saved, to move a file you can call 'File > Move' and proceed similar to above.

Comment: Finder creates files: archives.

Answer (score 0):

### Create a text file using TextEdit

1. Open the TextEdit app on your Mac (Applications > TextEdit, or use Spotlight, press Command-Space bar, to search, find and open TextEdit). TextEdit is a text editing and word processing tool that comes with your Mac.
2. In the TextEdit app, choose File > Open. TextEdit has two format modes: (a) plain text (.txt file) and (b) rich text (.rtf file). The difference is that .txt mode will not allow formatting, while .rtf mode will let you format like adding images, colors, tables etc.
3. Default format is rich text format. You can change this by going to TextEdit > Preferences and select Plain Text.
   [image]
4. You can also change the mode while you editing your text by going to Format > Make Plain Text or Format > Make Rich Text. If you change a .rtf file (rich text) to .txt file (plain text), your document will lose all formatting options.
   [image]
5. Create and edit your text file
6. And then go to File > Save to save your text file.
   [image]
7. Name your file and save it.
   [image]

Found this useful guide from **[macReports](https://macreports.com/how-to-create-a-text-txt-file-on-a-mac/)** website.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I spotlight tex, which will immediately suggest TextEdit.app, hit enter, edit my document and navigate to the directory and Save it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to create a text file directly in a (current) folder, at least in Mac Ventura.
After clicking on Finder, look under Finder>Services to find

[image: Finder>Services].

Click

`New Terminal at Folder`

After the blank terminal opens in the folder, type:

`> myfile.txt`

(including `>`) to generate the new text file in the folder.

Then click out of the terminal.

This, I think, is doable, without any additional mental burden or having to create scripts yourself.

Comment: How is this answer different from existing answers, most notably, the second highest voted one?

Answer (score -1):

Another workaround is to visit for example https://www.editpad.org/ and download a .txt file

Comment: We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Answers should be self-contained so others can find them by using the search feature.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Answer (score -5):

Have a PC with Windows on board.
In Windows Explorer, right-click inside any folder, choose Create text file. It creates the file.
Upload the file to any cloud service, or attach to a letter.
On your Mac, download the file wherever you want.
Profit!

Comment: Having a PC just for creating a txt file is an expensive overkill already. Mailing it breaks my barrier.

Comment: Yeah, it is better to spend $2 for a special utility: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/282512/338063