# Right-click for Creating a New Document - How?

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, contextual-menu

I am comfortable with creating new documents from command line on OS X (in my case El Capitan), but I wanted to explore the possibility to have Windows-like option to create a new document on right click. I have found the below script and I know that it needs running from Automator > Workflow > Run AppleScript:

```
set doc_list to {"Add new..."}
tell application "Finder"
    if not (exists folder "NewHere" of folder (path to application support from user domain)) then
        display dialog "This is the first time you've run NewHere." & return & return & "Files added to the list are located at" & return & "~/Library/Application Support/NewHere" & return & "Removing a file from this folder removes it from the list."
        make new folder at folder (path to application support from user domain) with properties {name:"NewHere"}
    else
        try
            set doc_list to doc_list & name of every file of folder "NewHere" of folder (path to application support from user domain) as list
        end try
    end if
    set my_file to choose from list doc_list with prompt "Choose a document to place here"
    if result is not false then
        set my_file to item 1 of my_file as string
        if my_file is "Add new..." then
            set new_file to choose file
            duplicate file new_file to folder "NewHere" of folder (path to application support from user domain) with replacing
            set my_name to text returned of (display dialog "Enter a name for the new file." default answer (name of new_file as text))
            my do_it((name of new_file as text), my_name)
        else
            set my_name to text returned of (display dialog "Enter a name for the new file." default answer my_file)
            my do_it(my_file, my_name)
        end if
    end if
end tell

on do_it(my_file, my_name)
    tell application "Finder" to set my_dest to (folder of the front window) as text
    set my_dest to my_dest & my_name as text
    set my_origin to (path to application support from user domain) & "NewHere:" & my_file as text
    do shell script "cp " & quoted form of (POSIX path of my_origin) & " " & quoted form of (POSIX path of my_dest)
    tell application "Finder" to open my_dest as alias
end do_it
```

It prompts me with a windows saying, "Choose a document to place here". What am I supposed to do to have the script working?

Comment: That _script_, the AppleScript _code_ in your question, in no way provides for a "Windows-like option to create a new document on right click" even if wrapped in an Automator Service workflow.

Comment: I was looking for something like this: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100509134904820

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an **AppleScript** I use as an **AppleScript** *application* so I can assign it the **TextEdit** *icon* and place it in the **Toolbar** of **Finder**. Then it's available to create a new text document at whatever location **Finder** is set to, that one has write permissions to. In other words, if one tries to create a new text document at a location that is only write accessible to e.g. `root` or any location one does not have specific write permissions to, then one is notified upon trying to create the new text document.

The *code* checks to see if a file of the same name already exists and if so notifies and brings back the **Save As:** *dialog box*.

Open **(Apple)Script Editor** and copy and paste the *code* below into the empty window and save it as **Create New Text File Here.app**. Make sure you select **Application** for **File Format:** in the **Save As:** *dialog box*.

Before adding it to the **Toolbar** of **Finder**, you'll want to change it's icon to that of which is used by **TextEdit**. You can open the **Get Info** *sheet* for each app and then copy and paste the one from **TextEdit.app** to the one in **Create New Text File Here.app**. Note that this is the icon displayed in the top left corner of the **Get Info** *sheet*.

Now that it has a nicer icon, drag and drop the new app to the location on the **Toolbar** of **Finder** you'd like for it to be. Note that depending on which version of OS X / macOS you may need to press the **Command ⌘** key while dragging the app to the **Toolbar** of **Finder**.

To use, just click the **Create New Text File Here.app** *icon* in the **Toolbar** of **Finder** and you'll be prompted for a name and the a new text document file will be created and opened from the current location of the **Finder** *window*.

---

```
on run
    my createNewTextFile()
end run


on createNewTextFile()

    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        set the currentFolder to (folder of the front window as alias)
    end tell

    tell me
        activate
        set fileName to ""
        repeat while fileName = ""
            display dialog "Save As:" with title "Create New Text File Here" default answer fileName buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2
            set fileName to text returned of the result
        end repeat
        if fileName ends with ".txt" then
            set newTextFile to POSIX path of currentFolder & fileName
        else
            set newTextFile to POSIX path of currentFolder & fileName & ".txt"
        end if

    end tell

    tell application "Finder"
        set itExists to (exists newTextFile as POSIX file)
    end tell

    tell me
        activate
        if itExists is false then
            try
                do shell script "touch \"" & newTextFile & "\"; open \"" & newTextFile & "\""
            on error
                display dialog "Cannot create the \"" & newTextFile & "\" file at this location!..." with title "Cannot Create File" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon stop
            end try
        else
            display dialog "The \"" & newTextFile & "\" file already exists!..." with title "File Already Exists" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 giving up after 5
            my createNewTextFile()
        end if
    end tell

end createNewTextFile
```

---

Note that this *code* could also be used in **Automator** for a *Service workflow*, however I've found that I'm already in **Finder** when I want to create a new text document and it's just easier to click the **Create New Text File Here.app** *icon* in the **Toolbar** of **Finder** then to *right-click* and choose from the already over populated **Services** *context menu* that I have.

Additionally, if you modify the *code* once the *script* is saved as an application and placed in the **Toolbar** of **Finder**, then you'll have to remove the icon from the **Toolbar** and then drag and drop the newly saved **Create New Text File Here.app** in order for it to work properly.

Comment: Note: drag and drop in finder works by holding down the Command key while dragging the .app file. At least in MacOS 10.12

Answer (score 1):

I have a script I run in the Finder with a keyboard shortcut from [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) (<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>) that pops-up a pick-list of file templates (stored in a template folder).  To add new templates just place them in that folder.

Posted on StackExchange a few years ago: [How to create a text file in a folder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84309/how-to-create-a-text-file-in-a-folder/84387#84387)

[image]

-ccs

Answer (score 1):

I've been using New File Menu from the Mac App Store to create new files via right-click, & it works just fine. It comes with 30 or so templates, but you can also create your own. Seems like it’s a lot easier solution.

You can find info about it at https://langui.net/new-file-menu/ & at https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/new-file-menu/id1064959555?mt=12.