# AppleScript current path for network drive or mount

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

I'm trying to create an AppleScript service that allows me to create a new text file in a folder in Finder. So I can right-click on a location and create a new text file. This is my flow so far:

[image: Apple script service flow]

It currently works fine for most folders. However, when I try and do this on a mounted network folder I get this error:

> The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “Can’t make «class cdis» "X folder" of application "Finder" into type text.”

Comment: Have a look at my answer [A: Right-click for Creating a New Document - How?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/276813/right-click-for-creating-a-new-document-how/276827?s=1|15.3851#276827). The _code_ in it can be use in an Automator Service workflow by itself with no need for other actions and works on mounted network volumes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the following [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/276827/71382), I edited the AppleScript in the first step to:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder"
        set the currentFolder to (folder of the front window as alias)
    end tell
    return currentFolder
end run
```

And now works correctly on network drives.