# Is it possible to create files directly in Folders?

Tags: finder, ms-office

I have just bought a MacBook and recently switched from Windows OS. Let's take the example of Microsoft Word documents. In Windows OS, I have a habit of making my MS Word files in the destination directory itself, so all I have to do is save my work later.

However with my limited knowledge of MacOS, I realise there seems to be no way to achieve this, I always make a new MS Word file and only at the saving stage then I require to go through the whole motion of entering my nested folders. If I have to work on multiple files that would be stored in the same destination folder, this process will become quite irritating if the destination is quite deep into other folders.

Is there a way to overcome this dilemma in MacOS in general for any application?

Comment: for which application

Comment: @Buscar웃 Actually the question extends to any application if possible. But the example I have been using is MS Word.

Comment: Mac applications will let you choose the save to folder, but only the firs time you do it. After that all new files from same app will be saved to same folder unless you chose no to. Is it that what you are talking about.

Comment: No what I meant is consider 1 application X, making file X1,X2,X3... X10. We might want X1,X2...X7 to be in Folder A(which is 5 folders deep), and I don't know a way to pre-make the files in Folder A so I can avoid going into 5x7 folders. However, I not only work with Folder A, I also want X8,X9,X10 to be in Folder B. So to your reply, no, I don't want a default folder to store all my files from 1 app X.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. I used to be Windows user long  time ago, and do not remember how do you PRE-MAKE file ? With what action or commands in Windows.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Go to your destination, right click ->New ->Shows MS apps or text document or new folder options. I think only some apps can do this, but seems like Mac supports no such features.

Comment: Maybe we can do that for you by modifying the contextual menu (the right click pop up)

Comment: @Buscar웃 Really we can? I can't find an option that allows creation of files in particular.

Comment: Nope, but what I am looking at is to modify the contextual menu pop up, so when you right click on your folder of choice, in there you can open the app of choice (like MS Word), but for now before testing it, I have to assume it will save the file you just created in to that folder. It is late for me, so more tomorrow, but you can read about modifying the contextual menu and adding service to it, to see if that is the way to go for you.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I see, thanks for your help and extra insights on what I can do in Mac, I think the answer provided is quite helpful.

Comment: Great, as long we found a solution for you

Comment: @Buscar웃 Actually do you know of a Apple SE chat that I could go to for queries? Might be better than awaiting answers here on the main site.

Comment: sorry I do not, but do the search for adding service to the contextual menu

Comment: You can access chat by clicking on the little burger-like icon at top right.

Comment: This, to me, looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). You don't need to create empty files in specific folders, you just need a rapid way to save them to specific folders. Open the specific folder[s] in Finder before you start, then when you're ready to Save, drag that folder's window bar icon into the Save box & the file picker will go to there.

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh cool, realised only from the answer Mac has a GUI feature to allow icons to be drag to terminal. And now instead of "cd" and "depth travelling" we could just drag the icon in a similar way w/o saving an initial copy elsewhere like what I required. Also in the midst of trying. Thanks for the new insight

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, you *can't* do it directly through the macOS GUI like in Windows, w/o any customizations.

You *can* use the **Terminal*** app (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to open Spotlight, then type `terminal`), by typing `cd`, then drag and drop the folder to it to get the whole file path; finally type `touch my newfile.docx`.

e.g.

```
cd /path/to/file
touch newfile.docx
```

---

many other alternative solutions [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84309/how-to-create-a-text-file-in-a-folder)

* coming from the Windows world, `terminal` it's like the `cmd.exe` (Command Prompt)

Comment: `touch` creates an empty (zero byte length) file, does Word handle this correctly? (And there is no need to `cd`, `touch path/to/file` works as well)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your prompt reply. As a previous Windows user, I only sticked to the GUI for completing day to day tasks and don’t really use the Command Prompt. Recently I got into a Computer Science course and people recommended me to get a MacBook for a better understanding of the UNIX environment, and that was my first encounter with Terminal, (no Command Prompt experience prior to that).

Comment: I have been searching for a long time how to extend my terminal knowledge to day to day task. Do you happen to know where I can read up on some of these because I wish to extend them beyond just creating text files for programming. Also, specifically for the creation of files, is it true that I could create any file as long as I know its extension?

Comment: @nohillside I don't get how your command works when you don't specify the name and extension of your file to be created. Sorry I'm new to UNIX.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth If you only want to create an empty file you can run `touch /path/to/file/newfile.docx` instead of `cd /path/to/file; touch newfile.docx`.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth To learn about Terminal, bash (the command line interpreter running in it) etc, google "Getting started with bash". There are tons of pages with information to get you started.

Comment: True, plus some tutorials on YouTube and StackOverflow family to answer specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

Since macOS does not have this type of context menu to simply add a New File of a certain type which is pre-filled with the required information, the closest you can do is an approach similar to what GNOME under Linux has:

- Create a Templates folder (it does not need to be called “Templates” though) which is easily accessible to you (maybe add it to the side panel of Finder afterwards)
- then open Word and without starting to type or change anything, save that empty file to your templates folder as a regular document (e.g. as “.docx”, not “.dotx” as this would be Word’s own way of storing templates and is not what you wanted)

Now, whenever you need to place multiple files of the same type, visit your templates folder, copy that file, navigate where you like to place them and paste them in the number of times you need them. Then rename the new files to the names of choice.

Other applications behaving in a similar manner (meaning being able to store files at custom locations) can be done in the same fashion.

No programming (adding services) or command line knowledge (using bash) is required with this solution.